# Maximum & minimum elements in a B+ Tree

Tags: algorithm, b-tree

I am trying to calculate how much would be the maximum and minimum number of elements in a B+ Tree with 4 levels of depth. (Root + 2 middle and leafs). `when n=75` (it's the order, which means each node has 75 pointers and 74 elements).

The root max amount of elements are `n-1 = 74`.
And the max amount of the root children are `n` which means `74 + 74*n`. (Depth 2). each one of children have also a max of `n` children which is `74 + 74*n + (n^2)*74`. (Depth 3).

Which means depth 4 with the leafs are (max amount of children):
`74 + 74*n + (n^2)*74 + (n^3)*74` ?

Comment: what does `n` stand for?

Comment: @PaulLo the order (which means each node has maximum of 75 pointers and 74 elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I have the answer, if anyone come across this:

Max - because the leafs should contain all of the values, the MAXIMUM value is: `(n-1)n^3 = 74*(75^3)`

Min: the root minimum is 2, and each of the two middle levels pointers minimum is floor() of `n/2` and the minimum of elements is (n/2-1). which means the formula to calculate is `2*(n/2)^2*(n/2-1) = 2*(38^2)*37`